# Adding Column In sparkdataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Hi I am trying to add one column in my spark dataframe and calculating value based on existing dataframe column. I am writing below code.

```
    val df1=spark.sql("select id,dt1,salary frm dbdt1.tabledt1")

    val df2=df1.withColumn("new_date",WHEN (month(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dt1), 'dd-MM- yyyy'))) 
    IN (01,02,03)) THEN 
    CONCAT(CONCAT(year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dt1), 'dd-MM- yyyy')))-1,'-'),
    substr(year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dt1), 'dd-MM-yyyy'))),3,4))
    .otherwise(CONCAT(CONCAT(year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dt1), 'dd-MM- yyyy'))),'-')
    ,SUBSTR(year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dt1), 'dd-MM-yyyy')))+1,3,4))))
```

But it always showing issue error: unclosed character literal. Can someone plase guide me how should i add this new column or modify the existing code.

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect syntax in many places. First I suggest you look at a few spark sql examples online and also the org.apache.spark.sql.functions API documentation because your use of WHEN, CONCAT, IN are all incorrect.

Scala strings are enclosed by double quotes, you appear to be using SQL string syntax.

`'dd-MM-yyyy'` should be `"dd-MM-yyyy"`

To reference a column dt1 on DataFrame df1 you can use one of the following:

```
df1("dt1")

col("dt1") // if you import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

$"dt1" // if you import spark.implicits._ locally
```

For example:

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("dt1")), 'dd-MM- yyyy')
```

Comment: tried but its showing issue error: not found: dt1.then i tried using "dt1" fro that its showing found string required column. i also tried 'dt1' for that its showing unclosed character literal.